# Как извлечь  WYSIWYG Editor из wordpress для использования в другом проекте

Tags: tinymce, wordpress

Вообщем-то сабж, как можно вынуть редактор текста wordpress и использовать его в своем проекте?

Господа, огромная просьба не говорить, что можно скачать TinyMce и сделать редактор. Задача именно та, которая указана в теме

Comment: вы понимаете абсурдность вопроса?) Хотя-бы объясните причины

Comment: Я еще раз говорю, если не можете ответить по сабжу, лучше не отвечайте. Мне нужно извлечь редактор и прикрутить его к другому скрипту, со всеми стилями и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

изучай разметку + javascript + css отвечающие за работу этого редактора, а потом дергай их из кода(иначе никак), тебе круто повезет если нарвешся на человека который этим уже занимался и даст тебе конкретные советы. Вообщето еще можно, чуть переверстать TinyMce и сделать его похожим на встроенный в вордпресс (если нужен такой же дизайн), а причину объясните?

Comment: В том-то и дело, что я понимаю как его вытащить. Нужно перелопатить кучу кода, чтобы понять как он зацеплен там. Я думал может кто уже делал и знает с чего начать.